# How can Transparency be enabled in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

I am running Cinnamon 2.0.13 (on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS).

How can I add transparency in the window borders?

Comment: It might work, but I strongly suggest that you do a upgrade. 1204 is not supported anymore, and the version of cinnamon that it provides you is probably outdated, so online guides probably don’t work. I don’t know if compositers support transparency well back then.

Answer (score 1):

Open Cinnamon Settings -> Themes dialog, there is an Other Settings tab. There you can choose the theme style to be transparent or not.

hope that helps.